# User gets rejected after system crash on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, login

The power went out on my PC running CentOS 6.3 while I was logged in as a regular user. Since then, when I try to login from the GUI, my screen flashes to black then returns to the login screen, without any message (as if my user was rejected). I can still login as root.

I checked the /etc/passwd file and everything is fine.

Here is a partial dump of the /var/log/messages lines, linked to the login and immediate logout:

```
Jan  7 09:06:59 localhost acpid: client connected from 3054[0:0]
Jan  7 09:06:59 localhost acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Jan  7 09:07:00 localhost rtkit-daemon[2701]: Sucessfully made thread 3107 of process 3107 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '42' high priority at nice level -11.
Jan  7 09:07:00 localhost rtkit-daemon[2701]: Sucessfully made thread 3109 of process 3107 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '42' RT at priority 5.
Jan  7 09:07:00 localhost gdm-simple-greeter[3094]: Gtk-WARNING: gtkwidget.c:5460: widget not within a GtkWindow
Jan  7 09:07:00 localhost rtkit-daemon[2701]: Sucessfully made thread 3113 of process 3107 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '42' RT at priority 5.
Jan  7 09:07:00 localhost rtkit-daemon[2701]: Sucessfully made thread 3114 of process 3107 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '42' RT at priority 5.
Jan  7 09:07:08 localhost acpid: client 3054[0:0] has disconnect
```

Any suggestion as to debug/solve this issue?

Comment: 1) Check space on /home. 2) Try to login to console (ctrl+shift+f2)

Comment: @dchirikov Unless CentOS does something oddball in that department, it's Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to the second virtual console.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Of course Ctrl+Alt+F2. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the issue.

I could login through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but could not issue any command. The `$PATH` variable had been tempered with and was not referring to the right directories. Fixing the `$PATH` solved the issue.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Was it changed in the startup scripts? Such a change must be investigated...